# Call controller/method instead of submit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am having a problem with trying to call a particular controller/method.  I am trying to call `myController/myMethod` but instead my `$_POST` is being posted to `myController` only.  I think that the reason why the `$_POST` is not working correctly is because of the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {          
    var $body = $('body'),
        $content = $('#content'),
        $form = $content.find('#loginform');
        $("input").uniform();       
        $form.wl_Form({
            status:false,
            onBeforeSubmit: function(data){
                $form.wl_Form('set','sent',false);
                if(data.username && data.password){
                    document.forms[0].submit();  // PROBLEM HERE
                }else{
                    $.wl_Alert('Enter password','warning','#content');
                }
                return false;
            }                             
        });         
        <?php if ($error_msg != ""): ?>
           $.wl_Alert('<?php echo $error_msg; ?>','info','#content');
        <?php endif; ?>
});  
</script>
```

I think that what is happening is that when there is `data.username && data.password` set, the form is being submitted but is not reaching the correct method that I need.

How can I modify the above javascript so that instead of submitting forms[0], the code should instead call `myController/myMethod`?  Here is the form code showing the controller and method that I am trying to call:

```
<form name="login" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>myController/myMethod" id="loginform" method="POST">
```

Comment: That is **not** how you use [`site_url()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)! Do this instead: `action="<?= html_escape(site_url('myController/myMethod'))?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
document.forms[0].submit();  // PROBLEM HERE
```

try and see what happens

```
document.login.action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>myController/myMethod";
document.login.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It looked like what you suggested should work, but it didn't work for me.  It doesn't seem to do anything when I try to login to the form.  Does not seem to submit . . .

Comment: @DanielAttard may be `return false` is causing problem. Try commenting that line and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also...........

```
<form action="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller/function_name" method="post">
       insert your elements
 </form>
```

when you submit it will go to the function in your controller and there you can access the elements which you submitted in your form using $_POST.......

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<form name="login" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>myController/myMethod" id="loginform" method="POST">`

in case you have removed the index.php using htaccess, or

`<form name="login" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/myController/myMethod" id="loginform" method="POST">`
 in case you have the index.php enabled.

How did you drtermine it is posting to myController? Did you put a debug line or exit in the constructor of the controller?
What is the output you get when you print the $_POST and exit in your `myMethod`